# redhat 7 + systemctl verification

Tags: rhel, chkconfig

I have try this on redhat 7

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type=service|grep iptables

or

systemctl list-unit-files --type=service|grep firewall
```

but not get any output - is this mean the iptables/firewall deleted from systemctl  ?

I see also that iptables installed on my linux redhat

```
# rpm -qa |grep iptables
iptables-1.4.21-16.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: `systemctl list-unit-files --type=service`. You should have googled before asking question.

Comment: why why why (-4) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type=service|grep iptables
```

Not display the iptables because iptables-services is not installed!

To installed the iptables service need to perform

```
yum install iptables-services



yum install iptables-services
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can    use subscription-manager to register.
Resolving Dependencies
 --> Running transaction check
 ---> Package iptables-services.x86_64 0:1.4.21-16.el7 will be installed
 --> Finished Dependency Resolution

 Dependencies Resolved

 ================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                     Arch                                 Version                                   Repository                            Size
================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
iptables-services                           x86_64                              1.4.21-16.el7                             updates                            50    k

Transaction Summary
 ================================================================================    ================================================================================
 Install  1 Package

Total download size: 50 k
Installed size: 24 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
iptables-services-1.4.21-16.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                 |  50 kB  00:00:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
Installing : iptables-services-1.4.21-16.el7.x86_64                                                                                                         1/1
  Verifying  : iptables-services-1.4.21-16.el7.x86_64                                                                                                         1/1

Installed:
iptables-services.x86_64 0:1.4.21-16.el7

Complete!
```

now  systemctl show it -:)

```
  # systemctl list-unit-files --type=service|grep iptables
  iptables.service                       disabled
```